# Is it possible to install Virtual Box or other free virtual machines on a cluster?

Tags: virtual-machine, high-performance

We have a CentOS HPC cluster and despite asking, the admins do not like to give us root access. I have more experience with finding the packages I need in Ubuntu's apt and conda-forge etc. I am wondering if it is possible to ask them to install a virtual machine for us and not be worried about us breaking down the OS. Does anyone know if that is possible, and if so, can multiple clusters be utilized within an Ubuntu virtual machine installed on a CentOS? I assume it is reasonable to expect loss of performance for parallel simulations, but even at a moderate loss I can live with it.

Comment: If they don't want to give you root, they'll be even less likely to want to give you a virtual machine.  Just give them a list of the packages you want installed.  Singularity is also popular on clusters, but that should be a last resort.

Comment: The Linux kernel already has built-in support for [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page).  It is very unlikely that your cluster admins would enable this for you because it would bypass the resource management and scheduling provided by the cluster (e.g. with slurm or torque).   BTW, it is possible to build a cluster based on virtualisation tech - I used to work on one called the Nectar Research Cloud in .au, which was based on [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/), but that was a tool to allow different groups to setup their own "virtual clusters" with VMs instead of real machines.

Comment: It is important to note that an openstack based cluster is a **very** different thing to a slurm or pbs/torque based cluster. It combines clustering & virtualisation, two things that are almost opposites. One of the huge differences is that it effectively required every research group to be capable of designing, building, and administering their own slurm/pbs style cluster on the openstack cluster. We provided training and tools and examples to help with and automate much of that, but it still required a lot more technical and sysadmin knowledge than most small research groups were capable of.

Comment: @user10489 unfortunately asking has not worked well so far, specially because of all the issues with version control etc. But they have already agreed and installed conda which has been somewhat helpful. Singularity looks interesting, why should it be a last resort?

Comment: @cas thanks for mentioning KVM, it's always good to learn about these additional tools just in case... I understand the issues you mentioned on a personal level as it is very hard for me to learn in the often opposing directions of system administration and topic-specific technical modeling and programing at the same time. Just looked into KVM, maybe I can ask them to install it. But from your second comment, am I understanding it correctly that normal virtualization methods such as KVM will not be able to access resources such as multiple compute nodes on clusters?

Comment: Singularity is a last resort because other things like OS native packages, python virtual environments, and environment modules should be considered first.  Only if singularity can't help should virtual machines be considered, and even then, VMs may not be appropriate or possible in the presence of other resource management policies.  Note that if python virtual environments can solve the problem, that can be used completely without administrator intervention.